# ERROR AL CREAR CAMPO CON LA DATA AL MYSQL PHPMYADMIN ( 1&1 hosting)

Tags: mysql, sql

Al crear el campo `dateee` me salta error, y es al poner el datatype...

Estoy usando un sql de hosting de pago (1&1) y me crea conflicto con una sentencia sql..

La sentencia:

```
ALTER TABLE publicaciones
ADD dateee DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Error:

> 1067 - Invalid default value for 'dateee'

Comment: `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` es para columnas con datos de tipo `TIMESTAMP` que es diferente a `DATETIME` intenta usar `NOW()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se debe a que seguramente estás usando una versión de MySQL anterior a 5.6.5. Si puedes ponerla al día, esto eliminará tu error.

Referencia: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html.

> As of MySQL 5.6.5, `TIMESTAMP` and `DATETIME` columns can be automatically initializated and updated to the current date and time (that is, the current timestamp). Before 5.6.5, this is true only for `TIMESTAMP`, and for at most one `TIMESTAMP` column per table.

Traducción:

> A partir de MySQL 5.6.5, columnas de tipo `TIMESTAMP` y `DATETIME` pueden inicializarse y ponerse al día automáticamente con la fecha y hora corriente (o sea, el timestamp corriente). Antes de 5.6.5, esto solo se podía con `TIMESTAMP`, y solo con un máximo de una columna de tipo `TIMESTAMP` por tabla.

Si no puedes poner tu MySQL al día, creo que solo tienes 2 opciones:

1. Cambiar el tipo de tu columna a `TIMESTAMP`.
2. Usar un trigger para poner el campo al día con la fecha y hora corriente.